# Web service Error (google translate API) WSDL error Java Eclipe Axis2

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, apache-axis, google-translate

I am working on a project where I am developing a web service which translate english to french using google translate api. I have managed to successfully create the server. But when I run my client I am getting an error. I am using Java, Eclipse, Axis2, Tomcat for the project.
This is my server code:

```
package com.GTWS;
import com.gtranslate.Language;
import com.gtranslate.Translator;

public class GoogleTranslateClass {

    public String toFrench(String sentence){
        Translator translate = Translator.getInstance();
        String textF = translate.translate(sentence, Language.ENGLISH, Language.FRENCH);
        return textF;
    }


}
```

Note that I am using an external  google translate api jar  for the purpose. I then create the web service and get it running. Eclipse creates the WSDL file which is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

-<wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="http://GTWS.com" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:ns="http://GTWS.com" xmlns:ns1="http://org.apache.axis2/xsd" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">

<wsdl:documentation> Please Type your service description here </wsdl:documentation>


-<wsdl:types>


-<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://GTWS.com" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="qualified">


-<xs:element name="toFrench">


-<xs:complexType>


-<xs:sequence>

<xs:element name="sentence" type="xs:string" nillable="true" minOccurs="0"/>

</xs:sequence>

</xs:complexType>

</xs:element>


-<xs:element name="toFrenchResponse">


-<xs:complexType>


-<xs:sequence>

<xs:element name="return" type="xs:string" nillable="true" minOccurs="0"/>

</xs:sequence>

</xs:complexType>

</xs:element>

</xs:schema>

</wsdl:types>


-<wsdl:message name="toFrenchRequest">

<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="ns:toFrench"/>

</wsdl:message>


-<wsdl:message name="toFrenchResponse">

<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="ns:toFrenchResponse"/>

</wsdl:message>


-<wsdl:portType name="GoogleTranslateClassPortType">


-<wsdl:operation name="toFrench">

<wsdl:input wsaw:Action="urn:toFrench" message="ns:toFrenchRequest"/>

<wsdl:output wsaw:Action="urn:toFrenchResponse" message="ns:toFrenchResponse"/>

</wsdl:operation>

</wsdl:portType>


-<wsdl:binding name="GoogleTranslateClassSoap11Binding" type="ns:GoogleTranslateClassPortType">

<soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>


-<wsdl:operation name="toFrench">

<soap:operation style="document" soapAction="urn:toFrench"/>


-<wsdl:input>

<soap:body use="literal"/>

</wsdl:input>


-<wsdl:output>

<soap:body use="literal"/>

</wsdl:output>

</wsdl:operation>

</wsdl:binding>


-<wsdl:binding name="GoogleTranslateClassSoap12Binding" type="ns:GoogleTranslateClassPortType">

<soap12:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>


-<wsdl:operation name="toFrench">

<soap12:operation style="document" soapAction="urn:toFrench"/>


-<wsdl:input>

<soap12:body use="literal"/>

</wsdl:input>


-<wsdl:output>

<soap12:body use="literal"/>

</wsdl:output>

</wsdl:operation>

</wsdl:binding>


-<wsdl:binding name="GoogleTranslateClassHttpBinding" type="ns:GoogleTranslateClassPortType">

<http:binding verb="POST"/>


-<wsdl:operation name="toFrench">

<http:operation location="toFrench"/>


-<wsdl:input>

<mime:content type="application/xml" part="parameters"/>

</wsdl:input>


-<wsdl:output>

<mime:content type="application/xml" part="parameters"/>

</wsdl:output>

</wsdl:operation>

</wsdl:binding>


-<wsdl:service name="GoogleTranslateClass">


-<wsdl:port name="GoogleTranslateClassHttpSoap11Endpoint" binding="ns:GoogleTranslateClassSoap11Binding">

<soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/GoogleTranslateWebServer/services/GoogleTranslateClass.GoogleTranslateClassHttpSoap11Endpoint/"/>

</wsdl:port>


-<wsdl:port name="GoogleTranslateClassHttpSoap12Endpoint" binding="ns:GoogleTranslateClassSoap12Binding">

<soap12:address location="http://localhost:8080/GoogleTranslateWebServer/services/GoogleTranslateClass.GoogleTranslateClassHttpSoap12Endpoint/"/>

</wsdl:port>


-<wsdl:port name="GoogleTranslateClassHttpEndpoint" binding="ns:GoogleTranslateClassHttpBinding">

<http:address location="http://localhost:8080/GoogleTranslateWebServer/services/GoogleTranslateClass.GoogleTranslateClassHttpEndpoint/"/>

</wsdl:port>

</wsdl:service>

</wsdl:definitions>
```

Then I go on to create the web client on eclipse using just Axis and it creates the proxy files. I create an object of the proxy class and call the method of toFrench as shown:

```
package com.GTWS;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;

import com.GTWS.*;
public class GTtester {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws RemoteException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        GoogleTranslateClassPortTypeProxy gtp = new GoogleTranslateClassPortTypeProxy();
        System.out.println(gtp.toFrench("hi there"));

    }

}
```

Later I am  getting the error of:

```
Jun 12, 2014 11:11:43 PM org.apache.axis.utils.JavaUtils isAttachmentSupported
WARNING: Unable to find required classes (javax.activation.DataHandler and javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart). Attachment support is disabled.
Exception in thread "main" AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: com/gtranslate/Translator
 faultActor: 
 faultNode: 
 faultDetail: 
    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:com/gtranslate/Translator
    at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.createFault(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:222)
    at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.endElement(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:129)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.endElement(DeserializationContext.java:1087)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1742)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2900)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:607)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:116)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:489)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:835)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:764)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:123)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1210)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:568)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:302)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.parse(DeserializationContext.java:227)
    at org.apache.axis.SOAPPart.getAsSOAPEnvelope(SOAPPart.java:696)
    at org.apache.axis.Message.getSOAPEnvelope(Message.java:435)
    at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.MustUnderstandChecker.invoke(MustUnderstandChecker.java:62)
    at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:206)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
    at com.GTWS.GoogleTranslateClassSoap11BindingStub.toFrench(GoogleTranslateClassSoap11BindingStub.java:108)
    at com.GTWS.GoogleTranslateClassPortTypeProxy.toFrench(GoogleTranslateClassPortTypeProxy.java:50)
    at com.GTWS.GTtester.main(GTtester.java:10)

    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}hostname:Karan

com/gtranslate/Translator
    at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.createFault(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:222)
    at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.endElement(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:129)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.endElement(DeserializationContext.java:1087)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1742)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2900)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:607)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:116)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:489)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:835)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:764)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:123)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1210)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:568)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:302)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.parse(DeserializationContext.java:227)
    at org.apache.axis.SOAPPart.getAsSOAPEnvelope(SOAPPart.java:696)
    at org.apache.axis.Message.getSOAPEnvelope(Message.java:435)
    at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.MustUnderstandChecker.invoke(MustUnderstandChecker.java:62)
    at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:206)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
    at com.GTWS.GoogleTranslateClassSoap11BindingStub.toFrench(GoogleTranslateClassSoap11BindingStub.java:108)
    at com.GTWS.GoogleTranslateClassPortTypeProxy.toFrench(GoogleTranslateClassPortTypeProxy.java:50)
    at com.GTWS.GTtester.main(GTtester.java:10)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the mail-1.4.jar and activation-1.1.jar to your classpath (WEB-INF/lib). Since you have mime type in the wsdl file.

```
WARNING: Unable to find required classes (javax.activation.DataHandler and javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart). Attachment support is disabled.
```